# Is there a rule for repeated letters when creating acronyms/initialisms/abbreviations?

Tags: thesis, masters, writing-style

I'm writing my master thesis and I've created an initialism that has the letter *S* repeated three times in a row (the initialism is OSSSP and stands for *Optimization Search Space Scope Parameters*). In my opinion, the constant repetition of letters in initialisms, abbreviations, and acronyms makes them look ugly, but I couldn't find a well-accepted rule for what to do in such scenarios.

Turn my initialism in something like 'OS3P' is an option, but it seems to be naive and informal. If I knew how to do it for this specific case, choosing synonyms to replace the original expression would be an option too. Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: How about OSP = "Optimization Scope Parameters"?

Comment: Would you consider "Parameterized Optimal Search Space" or POSS? Now that I see it in writing, I can't recommend it. But perhaps you'll find it amusing.

Comment: The problem with OS3P is that some people may believe it is a shorthand for OSPPP. For example, in France, C2I stands for "Certificat Informatique et Internet".

Comment: Are there any existing, similar abbreviations in common use, in your field? Avoiding confusion is probably more important than looking pretty.

Answer (score 7):

> Turn my initialism in something like 'OS3P' is an option, but it seems to be naive and informal.

There's no rule against such kind of initialisms, and I wouldn't consider it naive either. Actually, there are standards designated in similar ways, e.g. the [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) and [I<sup>2</sup>S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S) data busses, also spelled I2C and I2S.

Comment: +1 Similar acronyms occur in [names of well-known tech organizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) and [much-cited research papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783). Also: [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/i18n).

Comment: IMO the superscript notation is a little better. But really, when it becomes famous people will get used to whatever you call it :) There's a well-known algorithm in mathematics called the LLL-algorithm (after its three creators' initials) and we're fine with the triple L.

Comment: If you pick a superscript, be prepared that 99.9..% of the time it will be written without the superscript (except for official documentation I'd think) - at which point why bother in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

I doubt there's a rule. I agree that OSSSP is ugly. "OSP" for "optimum search parameters" with the full five word meaning when you first define it should work fine.